# use } into smarty string

Tags: templates, smarty

Im trying to use the key sign '}' inside a string of smarty template but it generate an error. The problem only ocurrs with '}' and not with '{´.
I need print:

var naciones = [{label:'Country', value:'1'}, {label:'Country', value:'2'}];

solution:

```
var naciones = [{/literal}{foreach from=$paises item=pa}{literal}{label:"{/literal}{$pa->getNacionalidad()}{literal}", value:"{/literal}{$pa->getId()}{literal}"},{/literal}{/foreach}{literal}];
```

example:

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
var naciones = [{/literal}
{foreach from=$paises item=pa}
{'{label:"'|cat:$pa->getNacionalidad()|cat:'", value:"'|cat:$pa->getId()|cat:'"'}{cat:'"}, '}{/foreach}{literal}];
$('#nacionalidad-ac').autocomplete({
  source:naciones,
  change: function(event, ui){
    $('#nacionalidad').val(ui.item.value);
  }
});
</script>
{/literal}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `{literal} {/literal}` tag to properly escape the curly braces in a Smarty template.  Also necessary for inline Javascript which has braces.

Comment: Best to avoid inline Javascript anyway.

Comment: thanks, i wrote: var naciones = [{/literal}{foreach from=$paises item=pa}{literal}{label:"{/literal}{$pa->getNacionalidad()}{literal}", value:"{/literal}{$pa->getId()}{literal}"},{/literal}{/foreach}{literal}];

Answer (score 2):

You can use {literal} to stop parsing. So a smarty template with a '{' would look like

```
This is just a text with a {$smartyString}
There is also an {literal} } {/literal} sign in here that could give you some trouble.
```

Comment: sure. im using literal tag but in my example there is a strange mix of opening/closed tags and i dont know how apply that principle.