# Smarty: How to display "{" and "}" special characters

Tags: smarty, special-characters

lets say I have a smarty variable ***TAKEN FROM DATABASE*** called

```
$myvar = "i am very happy {-: "
```

if I try to display it, it gave me "500 Internal Errors" because the string contains "{" character which is used by smarty. since its from the database, I dont have any control on the values it will give me... what I noticed if the string contains those characters it gives me error.

how can i display the spacial charater correctly without causing this errors?
Hope somebody can help!

Comment: Did you try looking at the documentation? It's there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [use } into smarty string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301308/use-into-smarty-string)

Comment: How you tired to "display it" ? Can you show us the place where it occurs in the template?

Comment: the value is coming from the database... so some user comments doesnt contain that special characters and some does... if I enclose it to literal tags then It will not display the contents of it

Comment: @sofl: I simply use {$myvar} for a test... please take note that the value comes from the database so I dont know If the string contains the special character or not

Comment: Have you tested this on another webserver yet?

Comment: The `500 Internal Errors` is not caused by the fact that your variable contains `{` character. You have to check somewhere else to find what is causing this error. show us the code may be we can help.

Comment: Try adding `ini_set('display_errors', true);` on top of your php file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try outputting your data between`{literal} {/literal}` tags. See [{literal}](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal) Smarty documentation.

Answer (score 5):

literal is not a good way to use it

```
{ldelim} for {
{rdelim} for }
```

is a good choice if you want to use them.

For example if you want to send a json like below

```
send('[{'ID':1},{'Answer':'A'}]');
```

the code will be like this in tpl file:

```
send('[{ldelim}'ID':{$smarty.session.user_id}{rdelim},{ldelim}'Answer':'A'{rdelim}]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to `str_replace()` the `$myvar` with the html-equivalents of these characters, before assigning it to smarty:

```
$myvar = "i am very happy {-: "
$myvar = str_replace(array('{','}'), array('&#123;', '&#125;'), $myvar);
$smarty->assign("myvar", $myvar);
```